# Call parent component function

Tags: react-native

Struggling with some basic react-native stuff.
I have a master-detail scenario.

I push an edit button on a list-item to get to a detail-view, in that view I add a save-button to a navigation bar. Plain and simple.

Navigation to the detail-screen is done by:

```js
this.props.navigator.push({
      component: EditScreen,
      passProps: {
        id:myID,
      },
      onPress: this.onSave,
      rightText: 'Save'
    });
}
```

When tapping the save-button on the navigationbar, the onSave method of the parent component is called missing some context of the modifications.

How is this done in react-native?
I'm a react-native beginner, just want a clear view on how this stuff happens before moving to some flux-inspired libs ;-)

**Update - Bind to this is not the problem**

Flow:

- I press a row which triggers an onEdit method passing in the ID of
  the item i want to edit
- onEdit pushes the EditScreen component on the navigator
- onEdit adds the rightText and onPress bound to this (onSave is bound in the constructor as stated by some comments/answers)
- When navigating to the EditScreen, the entity is fetched by its id
- I edit the entity and press 'Save'

When pressing save, I return to the parent view and have no reference to the entity. That's my problem, not the binding of the method.

Comment: Try "onPress : this.onSave.bind(this)" ?

Comment: that's not the problem, I use ES6 notation, constructor contains this.onSave = this.onSave.bind(this). "Problem" is when pressing onsave, I need the state from the childview (edit-view) containing the modified object.

Answer (score 0):

When using es6 classes, `this` is not automatically bound to the function, like React.createClass did. You have to manually bind `this` to the class functions. There are multiple ways of doing this.

- You can use es6 fat arrows to bind `this`:
   `onPress: () => this.onSave()`
- You can use Function.prototype.bind():
  `onPress: this.onSave.bind(this)`
- You can also bind them on the constructor, so the method is created only once (most performant way, but won't matter very much if you are just building regular UI; if your onSave function is being called 1000 times per frame, then this might be a good idea):

```js
constructor () {
  super()
  this.onSave = this.onSave.bind(this)
}
```